# Python 3 + Selenium: How to find this element by xpath?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

```
https://www.facebook.com/friends/requests/?fcref=jwl&outgoing=1
```

I want to click "See more request" in the "friend request sent"

```
<div id="outgoing_reqs_pager_57b87e5793eb04682598549" class="clearfix mtm uiMorePager stat_elem _646 _52jv">
   <div>
       <a class="pam uiBoxLightblue _5cz uiMorePagerPrimary" role="button" href="#" ajaxify="/friends/requests/outgoing/more/?page=2&page_size=10&pager_id=outgoing_reqs_pager_57b87e5793eb04682598549" rel="async">See More Requests</a>
<span class="uiMorePagerLoader pam uiBoxLightblue _5cz">
   </div>
</div>
```

I used this code but it doesn't work.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'outgoing_reqs_pager')]").click()
```

I got the error:

> Message: Element is not clickable at point (371.5, 23.166671752929688).  Other element would receive the click:

```
<input aria-owns="js_8" class="_1frb" name="q" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Facebook" role="combobox" aria-label="Search" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="js_5" aria-haspopup="true" type="text">
```

How to click it ? Thank you :)

Comment: Here you are find element successfully by using `xpath`.. this is problem with click. When selenium goes to click on this element may be other element overlayed here..so make sure by provided xPath only locate your desire element

Comment: Could you tell me which element do you want to locate here?? `div` or `a` or `span`??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Hello, I updated the question for detail

Comment: Ok then try with provided answer and let me know..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually here you are locating element by using partial id match, so may be this xpath is not unique and return multiple element.

`find_element` always returns first element by matching locator, may be it's return other element which is overlayed by other element instead of desire element that's why you are in trouble.

Here you should try using `link_text` to locate desire element by using their text as below :-

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("See More Requests").click()
```

Or using `partial_link_text` as below :-

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("See More Requests").click()
```

**Edited1** :- If you're still getting same exception you need to scroll first to reach that element using `exexute_script()` then click as below :-

```
link = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("See More Requests")

#now scroll to reach this link
driver.exexute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", link)

#now click on this link 
 link.click()
```

Or if you don't want to scroll, you can click using `exexute_script` without scrolling as below :-

```
link = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("See More Requests")

#now perform click using javascript
driver.exexute_script("arguments[0].click()", link)
```

**Edited2** :- If you want to click this link inside while loop until it appears, you need to implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until it present next time as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# now find link
link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "See More Requests")))

#now perform click one of these above using java_script
```

Comment: Hello, It only work when I scroll firefox to see what happen. If I do nothing, it click wrong position :D, so get same error

Comment: Ok then you need to scroll first using `exexute_script` to reach that element then perform click..try with updated answer and let me know

Comment: Or perform click directly using `exexute_script` without scrolling..try both options with updated answer and let me know

Comment: Hello, It click "see more requests" 1 time then showing an error: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"See More Requests"}   I use while loop to click until "see more requests" disapear

Comment: Then you need to implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until appear next time..

Comment: @NGuyen try second updated answer to find link using `WebDriverWait`..:)

Comment: Your code worked like a charm :). Thank you so much. Some Fb account, there is 2 "see more request" elements and the "see more requests" element I want to click is in secondary position. So, can you update the answers with xpath method ?

Comment: Then you can use this xpath : `(.//*[text() = 'See More Requests'])[2]`..for second link...:)

Comment: Great ! Thank you for helping me Saurabh Gaur